# Erroraaction in uploading file by FTP

Tags: powershell, error-handling, ftp

I have a file with IP address of servers. And script reads adress `($line)` by adress, but sometimes can occur address of server that will be down. It is necessary to script steel run till end of IP address. So I used `-Erroraction Continue` to `Set_FTPConnection` But script break anyway. How to solve this problem?

```
foreach ($line in $FTPServer)
    {
        Start-Transcript -Path $results            
        Write-Host -Object "ftp url: $line" 
        Set-FTPConnection -Credentials $FTPCredential -Server $line -Session MySession -UsePassive -ErrorAction Continue
        $Session = Get-FTPConnection -Session MySession
        $Session>>.\sessions.txt 
        #Write-Host $Error[0]
        if($session.UsePassive -eq "True"){$connect="OK"}
        else{$connect="FAIL"}

        foreach ($item in (Get-ChildItem .\Upload))
        {
            #Get-FTPChildItem -Session $Session -Path /htdocs #-Recurse
            Write-Host -Object "Uploading $item..."
            $Send= Add-FTPItem -Session $Session -Path $FTPPlace -LocalPath .\Upload\$item -Overwrite -ErrorAction Continue #>> .\up.txt #.\Upload\test.txt
            $item|gm >>.\up.txt
            if($Send.Name -eq $item.Name){$Rec="OK"}
            else{$Rec="!!!-FAIL-!!!"}
            $array = $line, $item, $connect, $Rec
            $FailTable=New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{"FTP Server"=$array[0]; "File"=$array[1];"Connected"=$array[2];"Uploaded"=$array[3]})
            Add-Content .\stats.txt $FailTable
        }
        Stop-Transcript
    }
```

Errors:
From my code

```
Transcript started, output file is .\logs.txt
ftp url: 10.80.59.173
Set-FTPConnection : Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "Unable to connect to the remote server"
At F:\DPI FTP\FTPUpload_v2.ps1:25 char:13
+             Set-FTPConnection -Credentials $FTPCredential -Server $li ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Set-FTPConnection
```

With `Test-NetConnection`

```
Start-Transcript : Transcription cannot be started.
At F:\DPI FTP\FTPUpload_v2.ps1:21 char:9
+         Start-Transcript -Path $results            #if $session.usepa ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Transcript], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotStartTranscription,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartTranscriptCommand

ftp url: 10.80.59.173
Test-NetConnection : The term 'Test-NetConnection' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Ch
eck the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At F:\DPI FTP\FTPUpload_v2.ps1:23 char:13
+         If (Test-NetConnection $line -Port '21')
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Test-NetConnection:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Transcript started, output file is .\logs.txt
ftp url: 10.80.59.170
Test-NetConnection : The term 'Test-NetConnection' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Ch
eck the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At F:\DPI FTP\FTPUpload_v2.ps1:23 char:13
+         If (Test-NetConnection $line -Port '21')
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Test-NetConnection:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

With If:

```
WARNING: Could not connect to 10.80.59.173
Start-Transcript : Transcription cannot be started.
At F:\DPI FTP\FTPUpload_v2.ps1:20 char:9
+         Start-Transcript -Path $results            #if $session.usepa ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Transcript], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotStartTranscription,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartTranscriptCommand


Stop-Transcript : An error occurred stopping transcription: The host is not currently transcribing.
At F:\DPI FTP\FTPUpload_v2.ps1:47 char:9
+         Stop-Transcript
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Stop-Transcript], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopTranscriptCommand
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the error that you receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Continue` is actually the default setting. It means that if a non-terminating error occurs, it will show the error and then should be continuing with the command and rest of the script. You could try `SilentlyContinue` to see if that helps.

Alternatively you could test if the IP Address is connectable first. If you're using Windows 8/Server 2012 or newer and PowerShell v4+ you could use `Test-NetConnection -Port 21` to do this specifically for the FTP port, if not you could use `Test-Connection` instead (which is a PS equivalent of Ping):

```
foreach ($line in $FTPServer)
{
    Start-Transcript -Path $results            
    Write-Host -Object "ftp url: $line" 

    If (Test-Connection $line) {

        Set-FTPConnection -Credentials $FTPCredential -Server $line -Session MySession -UsePassive -ErrorAction Continue
        $Session = Get-FTPConnection -Session MySession
        $Session>>.\sessions.txt 
        #Write-Host $Error[0]
        if($session.UsePassive -eq "True"){$connect="OK"}
        else{$connect="FAIL"}

        foreach ($item in (Get-ChildItem .\Upload))
        {
            #Get-FTPChildItem -Session $Session -Path /htdocs #-Recurse
            Write-Host -Object "Uploading $item..."
            $Send= Add-FTPItem -Session $Session -Path $FTPPlace -LocalPath .\Upload\$item -Overwrite -ErrorAction Continue #>> .\up.txt #.\Upload\test.txt
            $item|gm >>.\up.txt
            if($Send.Name -eq $item.Name){$Rec="OK"}
            else{$Rec="!!!-FAIL-!!!"}
            $array = $line, $item, $connect, $Rec
            $FailTable=New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{"FTP Server"=$array[0]; "File"=$array[1];"Connected"=$array[2];"Uploaded"=$array[3]})
            Add-Content .\stats.txt $FailTable
        }
        Stop-Transcript

    } Else {
        Write-Warning "Could not connect to $line"
    }
}
```

Comment: And when I use Win 7? I replaced Test-NetConnection with ping and issue is the same.

Comment: Can you edit your question with details of the error.

Comment: Amended my answer, see if it helps.

Comment: It works but i have error about transcript (look at question) and I need save staus "FAIL" in $FailTable - when I use If condition in hash-table will only servers with "OK". I need store info about unavailable servers.

Comment: It looks like `Start-Transcript` is having an issue overwriting the previous transcript file. A quick google suggests this can happen if the user running the script can write files but not modify them (per their ACLs). Try writing the transcript file to a different path, or manually removing the previous one, or check your rights.

Comment: To trap the Fail state where it doesn't connect, add your fail trapping code in to the Else { } block that currently has a write-warning.

Comment: Deleting $results doesn't change error occurancy. File is being create but error is the same.

Comment: It might be better to raise that issue as a separate question.